# Is "things such as this" singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects

Which of the following is correct?

> Things such as this make me happy.
>
> Things such as this makes me happy.

Is the subject "things" or "this"?

Comment: This is simple verb conjugation.

Answer (score 10):

*Things* is the subject, while *such as this* is a phrase which modifies *things*.  Take out the *such as this* to determine subject-verb agreement:

> Things make me happy.

Then put *such as this* back in:

> Things such as this make me happy.

That is the only correct option.

Comment: Whatever "this" is, you could always get two of them. That way, you could say, "Things such as _these_ make me happy." That is the other correct option. :^)